# theano.sandbox.cuda seems to be old GPU back-end and removed from Theano

Tags: python, theano, returnn

I'm getting an error message about old GPU back-end when I was trying to run rnn.py on returnn github page. "https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn"

Here's the error message:

SkipTest: You are importing theano.sandbox.cuda. This is the old GPU back-end and is removed from Theano. Use Theano 0.9 to use it. Even better, transition to the new GPU back-end! See https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29

Answer (score 1):

Please read [the documentation](https://returnn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). You should do this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This makes sure that you have the right Theano version (0.9.0).

But also, you probably want to use the TensorFlow backend now. (If you are already doing this, you might also just ignore the Theano warning. Or install Theano 0.9.0 if it annoys you. We want to remove the Theano dependency in the future when you are only using TensorFlow.)

Answer (score 1):

Although it is an old post, I drop my answer for future users. Just for your information, I got the same error in another project. This solved my problem:

`pip install theano==0.9.0`